# Locate phpunit bin in order to run tests with grunt

Tags: phpunit, gruntjs

I have installed phpunit globally using PEAR. Could you please advise how I can find where the 'bin' location for phpunit is on my xubuntu machine. Please advise if it is not possible to use grunt-phpunit with a global phpunit installation.

```
   phpunit:
    classes:
        dir: 'app/tests'
    options:
        bin: 'vendor/bin/phpunit'
        configuration: 'phpunit.xml'
        verbose: true
```

Comment: Maybe not relevant but you can use Composer instead of PEAR for the phpunit installation. It is a modern package manager that can help you to manage your php dependencies (and dev dependencies too).

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, I am using composer but I have phpunit installed globally because I use it in most of my projects. That bin will work if I use a local installation of phpunit but I am wanting to know if I can link to my global installation of phpunit.